# How do I place a DIV class in a specific position over another DIV class?

Tags: html, css

I have created a basic bar chart in CSS and HTML. It uses two DIV classes: A back bar and a front bar. The bar heights are determined based on percentage values provided in PHP. The bar classes were produced using the code below.

```
.backbar
{
    color: #000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 30px; //This width is altered using PHP values later in the code
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar
{
    color: #0026ff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; //The height and width are also altered later on
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid;
    background: #0026ff;
}
```

However, the front bars are currently positioned near the top of the back bars. How do I alter the class code so that the bottoms of the front bars are in the same position as the bottoms of the back bars? (This would be so much easier to explain if I could post images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your css to this:

```css
.backbar {
    color: #000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 30px;
    border: solid;
    position: relative;
}
.bar {
    color: #0026ff;
    height: 10%;
    background: #0026ff;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="backbar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSS positions

You can use css to position objects over one another with z-indices.

```
working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n74fr6f6/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those bars into a container

```
<div class="chart">
    <div class="backbar chart-bar"></div>
    <div class="bar chart-bar"></div>
</div>
```

And then give the bars absolute position

```
.chart {
    position: relative;
}
.chart-bar {
    background: #A6A6A6;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.backbar {
    width: 60px; /* increased length */
}

.bar {
    background: #0026ff; /* color seperator */
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boay2cp9/